# Android Parameter Passing Method

Tags: android

Which parameter passing method is used in Android? Pass by reference or Pass by Value? Please provide an Android Specific example for the same.

Comment: Ehh, the same way java work, since this is java...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All parameter passing in Java is by value.

[Here](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) is a nice article with all the details.

Answer (score 5):

just like a normal Java Application:

> Objects are passed by reference,
>   primitives are passed by value

Comment: The article posted by Hélène points out that Object references are passed by value, which has a different meaning than with primitives where their value is what's passed.